# sbt のプロキシ設定に、記号を含むパスワードを使用したい

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

社内のPCで scala が使いたくて sbt をインストールしたのですが、 `sbt new` したところ、プラグインが取得できませんでした。

Qiita でプロキシ設定を行う方法を見つけたので試したのですが、この方法ではうまくいきませんでした。

[sbt/activator のプロキシ設定(v0.13.9 / v1.3.7) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/pakuyuya/items/13dcb1ca3eeac75049d1)

原因として、proxy のパスワードに `+-[]{}()` を含む記号を使用しているからだと思っているのですが、sbtconfig.txt でこのような特殊文字をエスケープする方法がわかりません。
jvm に渡す引数では、特殊文字をどのように扱うのでしょうか？
また、そのような特殊文字の扱いについて記載されているページなどありましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

追記---

sbtconfig.txt の設定は以下のようにしています。

```
# Set the java args to high
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
...略...
-Dhttp.proxyHost=****.****.local
-Dhttp.proxyPassword="hoge{}<>()[]+-Password"
-Dhttp.proxyPort=****
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"
-Dhttps.proxyHost=****.****.local
-Dhttps.proxyPassword="hoge{}<>()[]+-Password"
-Dhttps.proxyPort=****
-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"
```

Wireshark で通信を見たところ、以下のようになっていました。

```
CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_****
Host: repo1.maven.org
Accept: text/html, ...略...
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
...略...
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED
...略...
```

色々調べてみたところ、 Windows では、 sbtconfig.txt を使用していないかもしれないみたいな情報にも行き当たりました。

[Windowsでsbt！@Git Bash - Qiita](https://qiita.com/seri/items/702fcb15dffdc9395805)

ただ、どのように修正すればよいか今のところ苦戦中です…

Comment: 関連があるのかどうかは不明ですが参考までにどうぞ。[JavaでHTTPSのサイトに認証付きプロキシ経由でアクセスしようとすると407エラー](https://qiita.com/kaakaa_hoe/items/d4fb11a3af035a287972)

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございました。 metropolis さんの意見を参考にして調べてみましたが、結局解決せず、プロキシのない環境で一度設定することで解決をみました。根本的な解決策がここに載せられず申し訳ありません...

Answer (score 0):

### 回答

sbtのプロキシ使用時について調べてみたところ、次のようなIssueが見つかりました。

[SBT proxy with authentication · Issue #366 · sbt/sbt · GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/366)

上記Issue、[wendersonferreira氏のコメント](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/366#issuecomment-305288280)にあるように、プロキシの設定でHTTPのものだけではなく、HTTPS、FTPについても設定すると直る可能性があります。

---

### 上記回答について

sbtのIssueをざっと確認したのですが、記号を含む場合についての問題は報告されていないようでした（全部確認した訳ではないので、見落としがあるかもしれませんが）。そこで、質問文内にある

> 原因に、proxy のパスワードに +-[]{}() を含む記号を使用しているからだと思っているのですが、

とのことで、プロキシでの認証エラーが出たと想定して回答させて頂きました。的外れでしたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。しかし、 https の情報は入力していました。明日、 ftp の情報を入力して再度試してみたいと思います。